# How to search filenames by regex with "find"

Tags: bash, unix

I was trying to find all files dated and all files 3 days or more ago.

```
find /home/test -name 'test.log.\d{4}-d{2}-d{2}.zip' -mtime 3
```

It is not listing anything. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

```
find /home/test -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*test\.log\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.zip' -mtime +3
```

1. `-name` uses *globular* expressions,
   aka wildcards. What you want is
   `-regex`
2. To use intervals as you intend, you
   need to tell `find` to use *Extended
   Regular Expressions* via the
   `-regextype posix-extended` flag
3. You need to escape out the periods
   because in regex a period has the
   special meaning of *any single
   character*.  What you want is a
   literal period denoted by `\.`
4. To match only those files that are
   *greater* than 3 days old, you need to prefix your number with a `+` as
   in `-mtime +3`.

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*test\.log\.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\.zip'
./test.log.1234-12-12.zip
```

Comment: If you happen to run on OS X, then use `-E`. `find -E . -regex 'theregex'` to take advantage of extended (modern) regular expressions.

Comment: `[0-9]{2}` hasn't worked for me on macOs, i had to use `[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: needed extended to use optional groups i.e.
`find -E . -iregex '^.*\.js(\.map)?$'`

Comment: @Chris see '-regextype posix-extended'

Comment: @SiegeX my previous comment was in case anyone might find it useful to know that in order to use optional groups you need to enable posix-extended and to give an example of what that looks like.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: it is also important to note that the regex is applied to the entire path, not only to a file or folder name; see `man find` > `-regex`

Comment: I didn't need `^` or `$` to mark the start and end, but the pattern did need to match the whole filename including the path part supplied as the first argument.

Answer (score 25):

Use -regex not -name, and be aware that the regex matches against what find would print, e.g. "/home/test/test.log" not "test.log"

Comment: Thanks to you and @dogbane for pointing out that a full path match is required.

Answer (score 21):

Start with:

```
find . -name '*.log.*.zip' -a -mtime +1
```

You may not need a regex, try:

```
 find . -name '*.log.*-*-*.zip' -a -mtime +1
```

You will want the ***+1*** in order to match 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 15):

Use `-regex`:

From the man page:

```
-regex pattern
       File name matches regular expression pattern.  This is a match on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file named './fubar3',  you  can  use  the
       regular expression '.*bar.' or '.*b.*3', but not 'b.*r3'.
```

Also, I don't believe `find` supports regex extensions such as `\d`. You need to use `[0-9]`.

```
find . -regex '.*test\.log\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\.zip'
```

Answer (score 7):

Just little elaboration of regex for search a directory and file

Find a directroy with name like book

```
find . -name "*book*" -type d
```

Find a file with name like book word

```
find . -name "*book*" -type f
```

Comment: You do not use regex with `find . -name "*book*" -type f`. Using "f" for filename is still useful as an answer since only filenames shall be searched for, but you should make clear that these are globular expressions as [the other answer makes clear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/11154841), not regex.