# Searching files by matching filename pattern and concatenating contents of the files

Tags: python, regex, bash, sorting, concatenation

I have 10 folders which contain files of the formated like so

```
"xaaNP_len_0.fa"
```

or

```
"xaaP_len_0.fa"
```

the "xaa" part is unique to the folder it is in.  the folders are named

```
[xaa, xab....xaj]
```

I want to concatenate all the files that match a specific pattern together.

For example I would like to concatenate all the

```
P_len_*.fa
```

where * is an integer from 0 to 100. This should not include the case where the "P" has an "N" to the left.

Next I want to concatenate all the

```
NP_len_*.fa
```

files together in the same manner across all 10 directories.e

The structure of the files is flat. For example

```
xaa/xaaNP_len_0.fa
xab/xabNP_len_0.fa
```

should all got into one file named

```
NP_len_0.fa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NEXT=''

for (( ;; )); do
    if [[ -n $NEXT ]]; then
        LINE=$NEXT
        NEXT=''
    else
        read LINE || break
    fi

    FILES=("$LINE")
    FORMAT=${LINE#???/???}

    while read LINE; do
        if [[ $LINE == ???/???"$FORMAT" ]]; then
            FILES+=("$LINE")
        else
            NEXT=$LINE
            break
        fi
    done

    echo "Concatenating ${FILES[*]} to $FORMAT."

    cat "${FILES[@]}" > "$FORMAT"
done < <(
    find xa?/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '???P_len_*.fa' | sort -k 1.14 -n
    find xa?/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '???NP_len_*.fa' | sort -k 1.15 -n
)
```

Answer (score 1):

for the second `NP_len_*.fa` pattern the `regex` can be like

```
.+NP_len_\d{1,3}.fa
```

and for the first one where you do not want the `N` us this

```
.+?[^N]P_len_\d{1,3}.fa
```

this one will match all patterns just except `N` before `P`. I have considered that folder names might grow in future about you `xaa` part. you can alternatively match for string of length 3 also.

Comment: @olliepower Please accept the answer if it helped you, it will help me as well as others who are looking for similar problem.

Comment: I am trying to implement right now. Can this be done with bash?

Comment: @olliepower I think it should, why don't you try once and let me know too.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make bash "find" work with regular expressions.

Comment: @olliepower take ref from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249779/how-to-use-regex-in-file-find   i also don know much about bash.