# Find files with extension with 5 characters or more

Tags: find, sh

I have a lot of residue files from a failed rsync-command. They all have a file extension of 5 (random)characters. Is there a command that can find all files with an extension of 4 characters and more recursively?

Example of a rsync residue filename: foo.jpg.hzmkjt7

I've already found out a way to prevent this with rsync, but all I need to do now is clean those leftovers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using bash, one option would be to use `globstar` like this:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable the shell option
echo **/*.?????   # to test which files are matched
rm **/*.?????     # if you're happy
```

The pattern matches any files in the current directory or any subdirectories that end in a `.` followed by 5 characters.

Rather than matching *any* character with a `?`, you could go more specific by changing the glob to something like `**/*.[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]]` to match 5 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: errr note the [bash]  tag was added by me. Not sure if it is the case, sorry. Removing it to prevent more confusion. Sorry!

Comment: @fedorqui probably not a good idea to do that in general! I'm gonna leave my answer there in case it's useful.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Will keep it in mind, of course. +1 for the nice approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regular expression for this:

```
find /your/dir -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\..{4,}$'
```

That is, look for files that end with `.` together with 4 or more.

Idea on how to use a regex from [How to use regex in file find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/1983854).

Comment: Nice, but worth noting that `-regex` is a non-standard feature provided by GNU find.

Comment: Yes. I don't have any non-GNU `find` here, but I see different solutions in the linked question that may accomplish this when no GNU find is available.