# Why is my bash randomly selecting files and renaming?

Tags: macos, bash, increment

On my Mac I am terminal scripting an increment rename of some files in a folder.  The files have a number at the end but from a top down approach they are in order:

```
foobar101.png
foobar107.png
foobar115.png
foobar121.png
foobar127.png
foobar133.png
foobar141.png
foobar145.png
foobar151.png
foobar155.png
```

When I create and run my loop it works:

```
DIR="/customlocation/on/mac"
add=1;
for thefile in $(find $DIR -name "*.png" ); do
    cd $DIR
    mv -v "${thefile}" foobar"${add}".png
    ((add++))  
done
```

However, when it runs the increment it's not as expected:

```
foobar101.png -> need foobar1.png but is foobar10.png
foobar107.png -> need foobar2.png but is foobar3.png
foobar115.png -> need foobar3.png but is foobar4.png
foobar121.png -> need foobar4.png but is foobar2.png
foobar127.png -> need foobar5.png but is foobar9.png
foobar133.png -> need foobar6.png but is foobar6.png
foobar141.png -> need foobar7.png but is foobar1.png
foobar145.png -> need foobar8.png but is foobar5.png
foobar151.png -> need foobar9.png but is foobar8.png
foobar155.png -> need foobar10.png but is foobar7.png
```

Ive tried searching on SO, Linux/Unix, Ask Ubuntu, and SuperUser but I don't see any questions that solve the issue of controlling the increment and I dont know if it's something in particular I should be looking at.  So how can I control the increment from the lowest number/filename instead of the Mac possibly randomly renaming with an increment so I get the desired output?

---

### EDIT:

After a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455576/why-is-my-bash-randomly-selecting-files-and-renaming#comment50880136_31455576) from Etan I was looking into the numerical values at the end and some of the files are named `foobarXXXX` and that is the issue.  The below answer, while awesome and a new approach I will look into still produces the same outcome because of some other files.  If I remove all files that are `foobarXXXX` and only leave files with values of `foobarXXX` my code and the code in fedorqui's answer work.  Is there a way then I can target this while in the loop process or do I have to target all names and test to see the length of values and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Are those files all in the same directory or do they span sub-directories? If they are in the same directory with no sub-directories then forget `find` here entirely and loop over a glob (which has a guaranteed sort order).

Comment: @EtanReisner they have been moved to one directory with no sub-dir

Comment: Then `for thefile in "$DIR/"*.png; do ...; done` should let you do what you want. Assuming your numbers are naively sortable and not naturally sortable. (The shell will naively sort `1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4`, etc. which you may want to consider in padding your renamed files to avoid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot rely on the order of a `find` command, which uses [the order that the VFS gives them to it in](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13451/what-is-the-directory-order-of-files-in-a-directory-used-by-ls-u).

You may, instead, want to `sort` it:

```
DIR="/customlocation/on/mac"
add=1;
while IFS= read -r thefile; do
    cd $DIR
    mv -v "${thefile}" foobar"${add}".png
    ((add++))  
done < <(find $DIR -name "*.png" | sort)
#-------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note this uses [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst), which feed the `while` loop:

> Process substitution is a form of redirection where the input or
>   output of a process (some sequence of commands) appear as a temporary
>   file.

Comment: I haven't dived into `IFS` do you know of some solid documentation on it?  SO's tag doesn't show a wide selection of items tagged as [tag:ifs].  On my Mac `man ifs` shows nothing.

Comment: `IFS` is not `if`. See [Word Splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) and [Shell Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Variables).

Comment: @Darth_Vader so you want to fetch those names being `foobarXXX` but not with `XXXX`? You may want to use a regex in the `find` command. See for example [Find files with extension with 5 characters or more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31314180/1983854) and let me know your thoughts. It shouldn't be complicated if the `foobar` part is known to just get those names having XXX.