# Regular Expressions two strings

Tags: regex

I do not understand much about regular expressions. I hope you can help me.

I have in a file the date of some files

```
Aug 15:07 file1.txt
Jul 15:04 file2.txt
Aug 15:05 file3.txt
Aug 15:05 file4.txt
Aug 2016 file5.txt
Jul 15:09 file6.txt
```

I want only files that start with 'Aug' AND have the time (:)

```
/^Aug :/
```

But doing that shows me all the files without exception

Comment: What is your environment/Language? Python/Javascript etc? Generic regex will be like https://regex101.com/r/mNyJsF/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/JuoZcQ/1

Comment: @Saleem I'm using batch

Comment: If you are using `findstr`, that is not qiote a regex, or at least a very limited one.

Answer (score 1):

This will look for filenames starting with 'Aug :' an this is not what you want.

Try `/^Aug [0-9]{1,2}:/` instead. It looks for filenames which:

- start with 'Aug '
- then one or two digits
- then the colon

Also, what is the bash command you're running ?

(You can test your regex at regex101.com, it's a good website or that ;-) )

Comment: Thank you! But I'm using BATCH and it does not work :(

Comment: In `findstr` regex, limiting quantifiers are not supported.

Comment: I don't know `findstr` but maybe you can use what's described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/6408940

Answer (score 1):

Use this Pattern `^Aug\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+\s+(.+$)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OLyRFB/2)

```
^           # Start of string/line
Aug         # "Aug"
\s          # <whitespace character>
+           # (one or more)(greedy)
[0-9]       # Character in [0-9] Character Class
+           # (one or more)(greedy)
:           # ":"
[0-9]       # Character in [0-9] Character Class
+           # (one or more)(greedy)
\s          # <whitespace character>
+           # (one or more)(greedy)
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  .         # Any character except line break
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
  $         # End of string/line
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Comment: In `findstr` regex, `+` and shorthand character classes like `\s` are not supported.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, the OP didn't specify anything about `findstr` at the time I gave an answer