# How do i find all file Which as name String+Number to it Linux

Tags: linux

**I have to find all files whose name start with String + Number like below**

ABC123_filedemo.txt

AB_451_filetxt

CD_789_demo.txt

demo_files_FD123.txt

d_files_re_SD_456.txt

**I have tried this Command But Not working**

```
export _date=`date "+%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S"`
find . -type f -iname  'AB*'  -exec mv {} /Demo_files"_"$_date \;
```

Comment: Are you using shell scripting? Consider adding tag for that.

Answer (score 1):

Is ".txt" relevant?  Then try:

```
find  ./  -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*[a-zA-Z]+.*[0-9]+\.txt' -exec <your stuff>
```

inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5249797/10514446

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple example:

```
find ./ -name "[a-zA-Z]*[0-9]*"
```

Every file here needs to start with a letter 'a'-'z' (small or large caps) and somewhere in the filename you need a digit `[0-9]`.