# script for removing files that are 1 hour old

Tags: unix, sh

I need shell script that runs every half an hour on cron and removes the files with extension (*.arc) that are 1 hour ,

old i tried mtime but that has a option only for days old not in terms of hours

it would be helpful if i can get a command or some logic which can run on all types of OS 
meaning (hp-ux,linux,rhel etc)

edit:(some of the servers in my work environment have OS that dont have mmin option is there a work around)

can anyone please tell how i wud use tmpwatch or temreaper do delete files (*.arc) older than 1 hr

thank you

Comment: hi thanks for the help ,but majority of the production servers have no mmin option

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you

[How to delete files older than X hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249578/how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-hours)

Seems to do what you are wanting to do!

Edit!

Maybe considerd kind of a hack, but maybe you code do something like this

```
touch -t 03061000 /tmp/datefile
```

This is supposed to create a file with a time stamp of March 6th 10:00

Next you can issue the command

```
find . -newer /tmp/datefile -print
```

to find the files thare are newer than this file and remove them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A link to someone else's question is not an answer.

Comment: No, but I dont seem to be able to mark as duplicate which I think this question is.

Comment: thanks guys but can u have a look at the edit

Comment: since im working on some critical systems(im a DBA and newbie in shellscripting ) my seniors expect  some thing solid ,thanks for your suggestion though