# Bash-Performing the same command on several directories

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, find

I want to create a script that will delete any files older than 7 days on a specified list of directories, but wondering what would be the best way to go about it...

I want to perform the following command on all directories specified:

```
find DIRECTORY_PATH -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

Maybe an array holding a list of directories, and loop through each element in the array performing the find command on that?

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Where do you have the list of paths? Because if it is in a file, you can loop through its lines and executing the `find` command.

Comment: Why not `find path1 path2 pathN <other commands>`?

Comment: Currently within the script, as it's easier to maintain... But would it be easier to place in a separate file?

Comment: It depends on how often you expect the list of directories to change. If never, then just hard-code them into the script. If frequently, it's good to shield changes in configuration from changes in the code. In between, it's a judgement call.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete files older than X hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249578/how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-hours)

Comment: Mmmm @l0b0 I disagree with the possible duplication: note that the OP's problem is how to loop through a list of dirs and perform the `find` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly store all the directories in a file, say `dirs.txt` and loop through it:

```
while read dir
do
  find "$dir" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
done < dirs.txt
```

Comment: Quick question to add to that... How do I close the file (dirs.txt) once I have finished reading from it?

Comment: You do not have to close it when doing the `while read ... do ... done < file`