# How do I list all files that are older than "X" hours in Centos7 using python/bash script?

Tags: python, linux, bash

How can I list all files that are older than "X"  hours using a python script or bash script in Centos7?

Many thx!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/249578/4611565

Comment: @manu190466 what`s wrong here? 

```#!/bin/bash

MKIT = $(find "/home/alex/")
TIME = $("-mmin +20")

if [$MKIT -name -type f $TIME];then
        echo"Files"
fi

```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GNU find command:

```
find [path] -mmin +[minutes]
```

Example: find all the files in / older than 2 hours:

```
find / -mmin +120
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` command :

```
find <path> <conditions> <actions>
```

File type condation:

```
-type f            # File
-type d            # Directory
-type l            # Symlink
```

Access time conditions :

```
-atime 0           # Last accessed between now and 24 hours ago
-atime +0          # Accessed more than 24 hours ago
-atime 1           # Accessed between 24 and 48 hours ago
-atime +1          # Accessed more than 48 hours ago
-atime -1          # Accessed less than 24 hours ago (same a 0)
-ctime -6h30m      # File status changed within the last 6 hours and 30 minutes
-mtime +1w         # Last modified more than 1 week ago
```

Actions :

```
-exec rm {} \;
-print
-delete
```

Also you can deal with size :

```
-size 8            # Exactly 8 512-bit blocks 
-size -128c        # Smaller than 128 bytes
-size 1440k        # Exactly 1440KiB
-size +10M         # Larger than 10MiB
-size +2G          # Larger than 2GiB
```

Examples:

```
find . -type f ctime -6h30m # File status changed within the last 6 hours and 30 minutes

find . -type f -mtime +29 # find files modified more than 30 days ago
```