# Laravel Database backup using mysqldump and delete old backup from directory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am taking backup of my database using mysqldump. But I want to take a backup of my database every one hour. that's why I want to delete my old backups. Only the last 3 backups will be kept in the backup directory. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Create a shell script to delete files older than x hours.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249578/how-to-delete-files-older-than-x-hours/249591

Call that script in your backup script/code.

Comment: is there any way to do this without a shell script?

Comment: Create a scheduled task in Laravel that will execute on an hourly basis. Use filemtime in PHP to get the file modification time. Delete files that are older than X hrs. Use mysqldump to create the backup. You can use exec() to run mysqldump command.